# chrome pull-refresh with fullpage library aotearoan

Tags: javascript, ios, angular, google-chrome, fullpage.js

I am using a library on angular for fullpage scrolling.

Whenever I swipe up my page on mobile browser ( chrome ) , opening chrome refresh popup. And its not good.

You can see this picture on the below.

[enter link description here](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/WhatsApp-Image-2021-11-15-at-16.13.59.jpeg)

Library : https://github.com/aotearoan/angular-fullpage

Demo Page : https://aotearoan.github.io/angular-fullpage/

If you open the demo link above from your phone (in chrome)
you will see the same problem.

I tried to reach the owner of the library but did not get a response.

Any ideas? How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to reach the owner of the library but did not get a response.

I'm the owner and you haven't reached me? :)

I can't reproduce your issue on the [demo page](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) (or any of [the fullPage.js examples](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#examples)) but you can probably get rid of the issue by using the fullPage.js option `scrollBar:true`.

Comment: Hello Alvaro , aotearoan/angular-fullpage library is it yours ?  I did not know that sory.
I opened a thread about it on Github aotearoan/angular-fullpage  but no one got back to me.

Comment: Nope, that's not the one :)
Have you tried mine instead? 
https://alvarotrigo.com/angular-fullpage/

Comment: Your library is very good :) but i making website for my friends and unfortunately i can't make any payment. Anyway, thank you very much for your comment.